# Python class flow-through

Tags: python, class, oop, datetime, inheritance

So, I am new(ish) to programming, and I'm fairly certain that I am doing something wrong, or at least sub-optimally, which is why I'm here, asking questions that require your mastery of the topic. I have chosen to omit the reams of code, because this really is a conceptual question. Please don't read any further if "stupid" questions bother you. For me, the answer(s) will be actually quite useful.

-- Details --

I use the native `datetime` [Python `date` format](https://docs.python-org/3.5/library/datetime.html#) in my script.

I also use a custom `class` called `EnhancedDate`, which stores a `datetime.date` object as `EnhancedDateObject.day`, and a number of other custom attributes / methods. These are mainly for tagging certain dates with certain attributes (eg. holidays, special days).

I also use a custom `class` called `EnhancedCalendar`, which stores a list of `EnhancedDate` objects, and other custom attributes / methods.

Both `EnhancedDate` and `EnhancedCalendar` are subclasses of `object` i.e.

```
class ClassName(object)
```

-- Questions --

I have four questions, three specific, and one general:

1. (specific)I have never been too comfortable with the multiple dot syntax in python. I understand Object.method() or Object.attribute, but I'm generally wary of Object.attribute.???. Is there a way to call the built-in month method of `datetime's date` object on my `EnhancedDate` object in one line?
2. (specific)Would subclassing `EnhancedDate` to `datetime's date` give me access to `datetime`'s built-in functions (such as [month](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#date-objects))? How would that work? I'm storing the `date` object as an attribute of `EnhancedDate` right now. Clearly I'd have to do something differently. Could you give me an example?
3. (specific)What is the best-practice structure for these methods / these data that would allow me to get the same result from `EnhancedDateObject.month` as from the following block?

   dateobj = EnhancedDateObject.day

   dateobj.month
4. (general)If you care to comment, I'd love to hear -- what else do you think I could be doing better in my approach?

Comment: Are the custom methods on `EnhancedDate` related to date / time manipulation or are they for other things (say printing out the time to the console or saving to a database)?

Comment: *What do you think would be the best/smoothest...*  -->  **primarily pinion-based**.

Comment: @SeanVieira both, actually. They're mainly for 'tagging' certain dates in various ways.

Comment: So would it be more proper to say `EnhancedDate` *is* a `datetime.date` or that it *has* a `datetime.date`?  In a sentence, what is the purpose of `EnhancedDate` (check to see if it is following the Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: @SeanVieira it's to hold a date with tags, essentially. I wanted to store each datetime object alongside information about each date.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a site for "general comments", so I'll ignore those parts and concentrate on the specific questions:

> I have never been too comfortable with the multiple dot syntax in
>   python. I understand Object.method() or Object.attribute, but I'm
>   generally wary of Object.attribute.???. Is there a way to call the
>   built-in month method of datetime's date object on my EnhancedDate
>   object in one line?

The `.` is a *scope resolution operator*. This is a fancy way of saying that the `.` is a way to "look into" a scope to resolve names.

When you write `object.method()` what you are saying is, *Look into the scope of object, and find the name method, and then call it*.

When you say `object.attribute.method()`, this means, *Look into the scope of object for a name attribute, then look into the scope of attribute for a name method, and call it*.

So in effect, the `.` is your "gateway" to access the members of an object.

> Would subclassing EnhancedDate to datetime's date give me
>   access to datetime's built-in functions (such as month)? How would
>   that work? I'm storing the date object as an attribute of EnhancedDate
>   right now. Clearly I'd have to do something differently. Could you
>   give me an example?

You have access to these already. You only subclass an object if you want to enrich the existing object by adding functionality to it (so in effect, making a better Date object) or tweak some behavior of that object that isn't available to it.

In your case, your calendar is composed of various date objects - for which you need enhanced methods. In this case, its best to create your own object, which then proxies the date object (as you are are doing now). You would then define methods that are specific to your object, and then pass on the other methods, such as `month` directly to the date object.

The clean way to do this is to provide direct access to the date object, from your `EnhancedDate` object: `EnchancedDate.date.month()` for example.

Comment: Wow, that was great, thanks.